# Is there a documented known way the yql web services truncate data requests?

Tags: xml, web-services, yql, yahoo-finance

I'm working with the stock market end of day feed. I pass multiple ticker symbols in one request. Around 400 or so I get an error that the string is too long. But anything less than that runs fine, but returns less symbols than I requested. I get back about 30-36% of the symbols I request. The kicker is that it doesn't matter how many I send... if I send 100, I get 36; if I send 10, I get 3.

Does anyone know the formatting of data returned/ implemented by that server, or a way I can find out? I'm fine to work with it in whatever form it takes, as long as I reliably understand it. Here's a sample string with one symbol "A":

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22A%22%2C%22A%22)&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys
```

Any other help in understanding the implementations of yql tables/ data sources would be great.

**Edit**:

I should mention that the lower than expected count is after parsing the xml returned, filtering out elements that have null values for key child elements such as "LastTradeDate" and "symbol."

Comment: Can you give some queries that reproduce this behaviour? I have tried with 1, 10 and 426 symbols and all returned the expected results.

Comment: @salathe Any chance you had a chance to look at the quality of the returned xml? If the symbols are currently in use, do you have full data points for all?

Comment: None have "full" data (a value in every field). Of the 426 symbols queried, 192 have been renamed and 17 don't exist.  I don't see this as a problem with YQL, but rather the stock symbols themselves (renaming being the main issue).

Comment: @salathe To your point of the symbols being valid, mine are... when I send 300, I know the vast majority (if not all) to be valid. For ex: NVDA (NVidia), RIMM (Research in Motion) don't come back.

Comment: @StatsViaCsh it sounds like two possible issues here: 1) YQL having a limit of total string length, resulting in not all your symbols returned; or 2) all symbols returned, but not all fields exist for each. Could you post a sample YQL query that isn't working and explain what you're expecting?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was indeed in the query string I was passing. I date requests in my code for data, and only the latest trading date data points were being returned. So apparently I need to run a separate procedure to query historical prices. Thanks for the help.

For future reference: yahoo.finance.quotes returns only the data from the latest trading day.. yahoo.finance.historicaldata can be queried by date.